# How to remove trailing white spaces from System.out.println(); Java

Tags: java, output, whitespace

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void fill(char mat[][], int x, int y, char prevV, char currV) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= mat.length || y < 0 || y >= mat.length)
        return;
    if (mat[x][y] != prevV)
        return;

    mat[x][y] = currV;

    fill(mat, x + 1, y, prevV, currV);
    fill(mat, x - 1, y, prevV, currV);
    fill(mat, x, y + 1, prevV, currV);
    fill(mat, x, y - 1, prevV, currV);
}

public static void replace(char mat[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++)
            if (mat[i][j] == 'O')
                mat[i][j] = 'v';

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
        if (mat[i][0] == 'v')
            fill(mat, i, 0, 'v', 'O');
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
        if (mat[i][mat.length - 1] == 'v')
            fill(mat, i, mat.length - 1, 'v', 'O');
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
        if (mat[0][i] == 'v')
            fill(mat, 0, i, 'v', 'O');
    for (int i = 0; i <mat.length; i++)
        if (mat[mat.length - 1][i] == 'v')
            fill(mat, mat.length - 1, i, 'v', 'O');

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++)
            if (mat[i][j] == 'v')
                mat[i][j] = 'X';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    char[][] mat = new char[n][m];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
    replace(mat);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The part I am having issues with is the main method, specifically this part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

My problem is at the end of each line there will be a white space because of the + " ".

How can I remove the white space at the end of each line

P.S. if this thread already exists, please link me to it because most of the whitespace solutions are with Strings and just using .trim();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't give the space character when its the end of the row.**

You could write like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (j < m - 1)
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
        else
            System.out.println(mat[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `println` in the else part and remove it from the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition for output white space:

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
    if (j < m - 1) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

besides the answer given, you can do this

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j =0; //we move j outside so that it can be accessed later 
    for( ; j < m -1; j++) { //notice we skip the last entry of the row
        System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(mat[i][j]); //we add the last entry of the row here.
}
```

the advantage is that you don't need to do an if check every iteration and there's minimal changes to your current codes.